# Access variables from config.php

Tags: php, variables, config, global

I'm beginner in php and I have a config.php file like this:

```
<?php   

 $config['dbUser'] = 'usertest';
 $conifg['dbPassword'] = 'passtest';
```

I need to load this variables in another php, I try with 'include_once' and don't work please could someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the fourth line... $config is spelt $conifg... Could that be a reason...??

Comment: I write wrong sorry, but in the config.php it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that you could [return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-157) values from included files? So you could do this:

```
<?php   

 $config['dbUser'] = 'usertest';
 $config['dbPassword'] = 'passtest'; 
 //   ^typo
 return $config;
```

And usage is

```
 $config = include("config.php");
```

Comment: I use this in a class and don't work

Answer (score 0):

A simple `include` should work.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
echo $config['dbUser'];
?>
```

Comment: This don't work in a class

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
```

at the top of the PHP file you want to access it in. 
You will then be able to access the config variables form that PHP file it is declared in. Handy for storing database connection string and other configuration.

You have also spelled config wrong at:

```
$conifg['dbPassword'] = 'passtest';
```

Answer (score 0):

try require instead of include. this will give an error if the config file is not found (ie wrong path).

```
require("config.php");
```

also, config entry for password is misspelled - *$conifg*.